# Connect endpoint and then connect consumer after some time in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

How to connect an endpoint(exchange-exchange-queue) in masstransit, accumulate data in the queue, and then, after some time, connect a consumer to this endpoint?

I wanted to do something like:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    for (var i = 0;; i++)
    {
        await _bus.Publish(new Event(i), stoppingToken);
        await Task.Delay(1_000, stoppingToken);
    }
});

// a command comes to connect the consumer

var endpoint = _bus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint();
await endpoint.Ready;

// I prepare the consumer, as soon as it is ready, I connect it, 
    then I read the data that has accumulated during the preparation 
    (my consumer needs to load the state before reading the data, 
    and also cannot skip the data during its preparation)

endpoint.ReceiveEndpoint.ConnectConsumer(() =>
    _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<EventConsumer>());
```

but this code will not create an exchange-exchange relationship, so the queue will be empty

Answer (score 0):

If the exchange bindings (wired to the receive endpoint, which ultimately is a queue) do not exist when messages are published, they are discarded by RabbitMQ.

You would need to connect the receive endpoint in advance, so that the messages end up in the queue.

Comment: I don't need messages before 'a command comes to connect the consumer', only messages after. My problem is that I don't know how to properly configure the ConnectReceiveEndpoint to get the exchange-exchange binding. I can't do: _bus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(c => c.Consumer<EventConsumer>()) because my consumer needs 'await' and some time to load the state

Comment: Well, that isn't how MassTransit works. Sorry.